# __asan_poison_memory_region doesn't work

Tags: gcc, address-sanitizer

I am trying the `allow_user_poisoning` feature of AddressSanitizer. Here is a simple reproducer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void __asan_poison_memory_region(void *p, int n);

void unit_test_2(void)
{
    int *p;

    p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

    __asan_poison_memory_region(p, sizeof(int));
    *p = 1;

    printf("%p:%d\n", p, *p);

    return;
}
```

ASAN's debug log says

```
==32232==AddressSanitizer Init done
Trying to poison memory region [0x00000147a040, 0x00000147a044)
0x147a040:1
```

ASAN tried to poison the memory but protection didn't work: data was erroneously written to poisoned address instead of reporting invalid access.

Did I misunderstand `__asan_poison_memory_region` or miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You are hit by the following item in [Asan FAQ](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer#faq):

```
Q: Why didn't ASan report an obviously invalid memory access in my code?

A1: If your errors is too obvious, compiler might have already optimized
    it out by the time Asan runs.
```

If you look at assembly code you'll see that compiler const-propagated assignment to `*p` to `printf` call:

```
mov DWORD PTR [rbx], 1
mov rsi, rbx
mov edx, 1
pop rbx
mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
xor eax, eax
jmp printf
```

Comment: I used -O0 to build the unit test, so gcc didn't optimize my code.
And I just check the assembly code, it worked as expected.

Comment: I will debug deeper to the libasan and update later.

Comment: @user14944 I don't see how debugging libasan would help you here, you'd need to debug GCC optimization passes in this case. Here's an [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/g/sZaGyK) which proves my suggestion.